# grouping and fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fields-for

I'm trying to create a form which allows me to submit new records for an association where the association inputs are grouped.

```
   class Product < AR::Base
     has_many :properties
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties
   end
```

Note that in the controller a series of properties are built for the product, so `@product.properties.empty? # => false`.

The below `fields_for` gives me the correct inputs with names such as `product[properties_attributes][0][value]`.

```
= form.fields_for :properties do |pform|                                                                                                                               
  = pform.input :value
```

But as soon as I try and group the association it no longer generates inputs with the correct names:

```
- @product.properties.group_by(&:group_name).each do |group_name, properties|
  %h3= group_name                                                       
  = form.fields_for properties do |pform|                                                                                                                               
    = pform.input :value
```

This create inputs which the `name` attribute like `product[product_property][value]` when in fact it should be `product[property_attributes][0][value]` as per the first example.

The Rails documentation suggests you can do this:

```
= form.fields_for :properties_attributes, properties do |pform|
```

But this gives an error "undefined method value for Array".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set up like this:

```
- @product.properties.group_by(&:group_name).each do |group_name, properties|
  %h3= group_name
  = form.fields_for :properties, properties do |pform|
    = pform.text_field :value
```

It should work fine, since you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties` rails know that it's supposed to create fields for `properties_attributes`. Moreover you may want to add
`attr_accessible :properties_attributes` if you are using one of newest Rails and if you didn't add it to your model yet ;)

Also, if you want to make some decision base on single property you may use the following form as well:

```
- @product.properties.group_by(&:group_name).each do |group_name, properties|
  %h3= group_name
  - properties.each do |property|
    = form.fields_for :properties, property do |pform|
      = pform.text_field :value
```

Both of them are nicely described here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for under `One-To-Many` section

Comment: This seems to work, I don't know why I didn't try `:properties` instead of `:property_attributes`. Will accept shortly.

Comment: This answer has stood the test of time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a clean 'Rails' solution to this sort of thing, but I often handle these types of situations more manually. eg - Loop through the groups and conditionally show only those properties that are in a particular group.

```
class Product < AR::Base
  has_many :properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties

  def group_names
    properties.map(&:group_name).uniq.sort
  end
end
```

In the view

```
- for group_name in product.group_names
  = form.fields_for :properties do |pform|
    %h3= group_name
    - if pform.object.group_name.eql?(group_name)
      = pform.input :value
```

There may be a little overhead with this, getting the list of properties from product repeatedly.  You may be able to modify your has_many :properties association to retrieve the properties in group_name order - then you could add the %h3 when it's a new group.

```
- previous_group_name = nil
= form.fields_for :properties do |pform|
  - if pform.object.group_name != previous_group_name
    %h3= pform.object.group_name
  = pform.input :value
  - previous_group_name = pform.object.group_name
```

Some ideas for you...